# Stream is not re-rendering when switching tabs on flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a stream builder that shows a list of "posts" from a server. I have used the BLoC architecture to accomplish this. **But for some reason when I switch tabs and back the posts disappear how can I keep the posts from disappearing or have them re-render?** Below is small part of my code I think is relevant I can add more if needed:

**Tab UI (not all the code, file containing BLoC is imported at top):**

```
  @override
  void initState() {
   bloc.fetchMyPosts();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Posts", style: Style.appBarStyle),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                text: "My Posts",
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "My Other Posts",
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Posts(stream: bloc.myPosts), //Stream builder with SliverChildBuilderDelegate
            Posts(stream:bloc.myOtherPosts),//Stream builder with SliverChildBuilderDelegate
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Stream Builder (Posts):**

```
Widget Posts({Stream stream, //Other variables}) {
  return StreamBuilder(
      stream:stream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        switch(snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
            return Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  child: Text("Please check if you are connected to the internet"),
                ),
              ],
            );
            break;
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            if (snapshot.data == null){
              return Container(
                  color: Color(0xFFF4F4FF),
                  child: Container(child:Center(child:Text(variable?"Text one":"Text two"))));
            } else return Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text("Loading"),
                ),
              ],
            );
            break;
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Container(
                  color:Colors.white,
                  child: CustomScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: false,
                    slivers: <Widget>[
                      SliverPadding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24.0),
                        sliver: SliverList(
                          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                                (context, index) => PostCard(post:snapshot.data[index],//variables),
                            childCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ));
            }
            if (snapshot.data == null){
              return Container(
                  color: Color(0xFFF4F4FF),
                  child: Container(child:Center(child:Text(variable?"Text one":"Text two"))));
            }
        }
      });
}
```

**BLoC:**

```
class Bloc{

  ApiClient _client = ApiClient();

  final _myPosts = BehaviourSubject<List<Post>>();
  final _myOtherPosts = BehaviourSubject<List<Post>>();

  Stream<List<Post>> get myPosts => _myPosts.stream;
   Stream<List<Post>> get myOtherPosts => _myOtherPosts.stream;

  fetchMyPosts() async {
    List<Post> posts = await _client.getMyPosts();
    _myPosts.sink.add(posts);
  }

  fetchMyOtherPosts() async {
    List<Post> posts = await _client.getMyOtherPosts();
    _myOtherPosts.sink.add(posts);
  }


  dispose(){
    _myPosts.close();
     _myOtherPosts.close();
  }

}

final bloc = Bloc();
```

**Main Screen:**

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  UserBloc userBloc;

  MainScreen({this.userBloc});

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {


  int _currentIndex = 0;

  onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  Widget getPage(int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return PostPage(myHandle: widget.userBloc.userValue);
    }
    if (index == 1) {
      return PageOne();
    }
    if (index == 3) {
      return  PageTwo();
    }
    if (index == 4) {
      return PageThree(userBloc: widget.userBloc);
    }

    return PostPage(userBloc: widget.userBloc);
  }

  Widget customNav() {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.library_books),
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _currentIndex = 0;
                })),
            // MORE ICONS but similar code
          ],
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          getPage(_currentIndex),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: customNav(),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: that's a minor note, but in `initState` override you probably should first call `super.initState` and only then do your custom stuff

Comment: @AlexanderArendar will do, from what I read somewhere thought it didn't matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this code i put some comments. I can do this using streambuilder and bloc pattern simulating an async data fetching with future delayed. This widget is working but you will need adapt to your needs.

```
class TabWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabWidgetState createState() => _TabWidgetState();
}

class _TabWidgetState extends State<TabWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  Bloc _bloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bloc = Bloc(); // can be your bloc.fetchData();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _bloc?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //i really recomment using stream builder to create all layout
    // if length property is dynamic
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Tab screen"),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab( text: "My Posts" ),
              Tab( text: "Other" ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

        body: StreamBuilder<List<Widget>>(
            stream: _bloc.getTabData,
            builder: (context, asyncSnapshot){
              switch(asyncSnapshot.connectionState){
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text("handle none state here, this is because i am simulate a async event"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                  break;

                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Text("Loading data..."),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                  break;

                case ConnectionState.active:
                case ConnectionState.done:
                   //assuming that snapshot has valid data...
                  return TabBarView(
                    children:[
                      asyncSnapshot.data[0],
                      asyncSnapshot.data[1],
                    ],
                  );
              }
            }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}

class Bloc{
  // post items
  // just to simulate data
  List<Widget> _tabList1 = List.generate(10, (index){ return Text("TAB 1 Item $index");} );
  List<Widget> _tabList2 = List.generate(10, (index){ return Text("TAB 2 Item $index");} );

  //tab's data stream
  PublishSubject< List<Widget>> _tabData = PublishSubject();
  Observable<List<Widget>> get getTabData => _tabData.stream;

  Bloc() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      List<Widget> tabDataWidgets = List();
      // adding tab's data
      tabDataWidgets.add( ListView(
        children: _tabList1,
      ) );

      tabDataWidgets.add( ListView(
        children: _tabList2,
      ) );

      _addingToSink( tabDataWidgets );
    });
  }

  void _addingToSink( final List<Widget> list) => _tabData.sink.add( list );

  dispose(){ _tabData?.close(); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually using two stream builders one for each tab maybe that's why they weren't re-rendering. Each one is using a SliverChildBuilderDelegate so might be harder to put them into one stream builder but I'll see.

Comment: I updated my stream builder using what you mentioned but still split it up into two stream builders, I used BehaviourSubject instead of PublishSubject and it seemed to work, but it keeps falling into the ConnectionState.waiting case when there is no data how can I stop this?

Comment: probably because you're adding nothing to your stream sink when there is no data and the stream listener still await. Try add to sink an empty data list or even null and handle this in connectionState active or done

Comment: Just had an issue, this tab bar view is part of a bottom navigation bar. One tab has data and the other does not, if I go to the tab that has no data then click on an icon in the bottom navigation to go to a different page. When I come back to the original tab bar view with the tab with the data, it shows "no data" when it did previously. I have to switch back and forth for it to load properly, any reason why?

Comment: mate I really need to see the more code to provide you my opinion about it. Probably the entire screen code, sorry....

Comment: The issue can be inside your bloc class... I really need see more code

Comment: I added more code, thanks for your help! Let me know if you need more info

Comment: It's not this mate... last week I had hard work in some codes that I have to show for my client today yet... I promise that tomorrow I will put some things here but  I can't grant if will solve the entire problem...

Comment: No worries! I was thinking of making a separate question but didn't. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `PublishSubject` to `BehaviourSubject` and it seemed to work. I used it in conjunction with Marcos Boaventura's answer as well. Although I used two stream builders.

**PublishSubject**: Starts empty and only emits new elements.

**BehaviorSubject**: It needs an initial value and replays it or the latest element to new subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it another way like as I have take two Streem variable Example

```
 final Stream<QuerySnapshot> showpost = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("post")
        .snapshots();
 final Stream<QuerySnapshot> showpost2 = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("post")
        .snapshots();
```

And two-stream i have use two-variable ;